# Changing existing Excel data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of telephone numbers already in Excel. None of them have a 0 in front of them .I need to out a zero in front of them for my touch dialling phone system. Is it possible to create a rule that allows me to do this retrospectively?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) to add a 0 in front of the existing text. Create a new column enter the function and edit A1 to be the first cell. The use fill down to copy the function down to other rows.

```
=CONCATENATE("0",A1)
```